# how to respond from client to server and server to client using signalr

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am new to signalr,
I have gone through a number of tutorials where I have seen the chat room application where server has been configured on console app and client on javascript, as you open the multiple instances of browsers you can chat between them.

My question is how to chat between server to client rather than between clients.
lets say I build a server on winform. On that winform I have datagridview which shows me the number of clients connected to server and I want to send a message to client #2 , then the client #2 will also reply me which I will show in a textbox on winform.

My Client Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";


        var chat = $.connection.myHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {

            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };

        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));

        $('#message').focus();

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {

                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());

                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Myhub.cs:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void getname(string name)
    {


    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId); 
        string RemoteIpAddress = Context.Request.GetRemoteIpAddress();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }


    public void acknowledgment(string ack)
    {
        Clients.Caller.acknowledgment(ack);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: There's really no difference here. Did you try something already?

Comment: yes i am trying to paste my code in comments but it is saying too long characters. where should i paste my code ?

Comment: @makhan You should past it within your question, click on edit and add it there.

Comment: Now we can try to help you:)

Comment: i am waiting for your reply @user3378165

Comment: you can see my code @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: @makhan I'm sorry, but I don't know how to help you...

Comment: makhan, the code you pasted does not really show how you are trying to send from your application to the client, it just shows the Hub. What did you try, in order to achieve your goals? did you get any error messages while attempting to send to a client? do you receive events for client connections at all? can you send to all clients but not to a single one?please provide more details so we are able to understand the exact problem

Answer (score 1):

Code seems good. try to add following code in startup.cs

```
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableJSONP = true
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
```